# Extracting Items over an List<T> of List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am trying to retrieve records from a `List<T>` of `List<T>` and seek your help in getting it.

I am trying to fetch items where `overdues.Accounts.AccountId = 'JKB1'` and how can i do it over the below List Items.

```
public class OverdueModel
    {
        public string Slab { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }
        public double Percentage { get; set; }
        public List<OverdueSlabAccounts> Accounts { get; set; }
    }

    public class OverdueSlabAccounts
    {
        public string AccountId { get; set; }
        public string AccountName { get; set; }
        public string SalesCode { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        }


void Main(){
    List<OverdueModel> overdues = new List<OverdueModel>();
    List<OverdueSlabAccounts> accounts = new List<OverdueSlabAccounts>();

    //For T3
    accounts.Clear();
    accounts.Add(new OverdueSlabAccounts()
        {
            AccountId = "JKB1",
            AccountName = "JKB1",
            SalesCode = "JKB",
            Value = "500"
        });

    accounts.Add(new OverdueSlabAccounts()
        {
            AccountId = "JKB2",
            AccountName = "JKB2",
            SalesCode = "JKB",
            Value = "500"
        });

    overdues.Add(new OverdueModel()
    {
        Slab = "T3",
        Value = 1000,
        Percentage = 0,
        Accounts = accounts
    });

    //For T4
    accounts.Clear();
    accounts.Add(new OverdueSlabAccounts()
        {
            AccountId = "JKB1",
            AccountName = "JKB1",
            SalesCode = "JKB",
            Value = "1000"
        });

    overdues.Add(new OverdueModel()
    {
        Slab = "T4",
        Value = 1000,
        Percentage = 0,
        Accounts = accounts
    });

}
```

Comment: Thank You to everyone who helped me. I am oblige here to mark as answer to the first reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Where` and `Any` in combination for this :

```
var result = overdues
                .Where(overdue => overdue.Accounts
                                     .Any(account => account.AccountId == "JKB1"));
```

This will filter those overdues for which associated any Account has `AccountId` **JKB1**

Answer (score 1):

You could use Linq for the purpose

```
var filteredList = overdues.Where(x=>x.Accounts.Any(c=>c.AccountId=="JKB1"));
```

For more information on `Where` and `Any`

- Enumerable.Where : [Refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8)
- Enumerable.Any : [Refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8)

Output

[image]

Comment: Can you share me your `LinqPad` working, I am just curious to know how it can be done with `C# classes`

Comment: You could use filteredList.Dump() to print in Linqpad.

Comment: var filteredList = overdues.Where(x=>x.Accounts.Any(c=>c.AccountId=="JKB1"));
 filteredList.Dump();

Comment: That's the only change from the code you have given in OP, other than of course, adding System.Linq in namespaces

Comment: Thank you very much with the `LinqPad` working and very informative detail response. This helped me lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 var account = accounts.Find(x => x.AccountId.Contains("JKB1")));
```

or

```
var account = accounts.Find(x => x.AccountId.Equals("JKB1")));
```

this will get you the specific account Id you are looking for.