# Filter from List<T> of List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

My Concern is based on the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59083673/extracting-items-over-an-listt-of-listt/59083729#59083729) I had asked earlier and got the resolution.

I initially thought I am getting the correct response, but to see I am not. My Data is like this:

[image]

and If I filtered like this

`var result = overdues.Where(a=>a.Accounts.Any(b=>b.AccountId.Equals("JKB2")));`

I am getting the result like this:

[image]

But I want the result only to have Accounts equalling to JKB2 not Accounts that have JKB2. Hence what I have highlighted down here should be in the result and not others:

[image]

Technically, the result should be like this ( I just wrote a pseudocode in the form of JSON):

```
    [
    {
    Slab: T3,
    Value: 500,
    Percentage: 0
    Accounts: {
    AccountId:JKB2,
    AccountName:JKB2,
    SalesCode:JKB,
    Value:500
    }
    },
{
    Slab: T5,
    Value: 500,
    Percentage: 0
    Accounts: {
    AccountId:JKB2,
    AccountName:JKB2,
    SalesCode:JKB,
    Value:500
    }
    }
    ]
```

My LinqPad working is here:

```
public class OverdueModel
    {
        public string Slab { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }
        public double Percentage { get; set; }
        public List<OverdueSlabAccounts> Accounts { get; set; }
    }

    public class OverdueSlabAccounts
    {
        public string AccountId { get; set; }
        public string AccountName { get; set; }
        public string SalesCode { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }


void Main(){
    List<OverdueModel> overdues = new List<OverdueModel>();
    List<OverdueSlabAccounts> accounts1 = new List<OverdueSlabAccounts>();
    List<OverdueSlabAccounts> accounts2 = new List<OverdueSlabAccounts>();
    List<OverdueSlabAccounts> accounts3 = new List<OverdueSlabAccounts>();

    //For T3
    accounts1.Add(new OverdueSlabAccounts()
        {
            AccountId = "JKB1",
            AccountName = "JKB1",
            SalesCode = "JKB",
            Value = "500"
        });

    accounts1.Add(new OverdueSlabAccounts()
        {
            AccountId = "JKB2",
            AccountName = "JKB2",
            SalesCode = "JKB",
            Value = "500"
        });

    overdues.Add(new OverdueModel()
    {
        Slab = "T3",
        Value = 1000,
        Percentage = 0,
        Accounts= accounts1
    });

    //For T4
    accounts2.Add(new OverdueSlabAccounts()
        {
            AccountId = "JKB1",
            AccountName = "JKB1",
            SalesCode = "JKB",
            Value = "1000"
        });

    overdues.Add(new OverdueModel()
    {
        Slab = "T4",
        Value = 1000,
        Percentage = 0,
        Accounts= accounts2
    });

    //For T5
    accounts3.Add(new OverdueSlabAccounts()
        {
            AccountId = "JKB1",
            AccountName = "JKB1",
            SalesCode = "JKB",
            Value = "1000"
        });

    accounts3.Add(new OverdueSlabAccounts()
        {
            AccountId = "JKB2",
            AccountName = "JKB2",
            SalesCode = "JKB",
            Value = "500"
        });

    accounts3.Add(new OverdueSlabAccounts()
        {
            AccountId = "JKB3",
            AccountName = "JKB3",
            SalesCode = "JKB",
            Value = "500"
        });

    overdues.Add(new OverdueModel()
    {
        Slab = "T5",
        Value = 2000,
        Percentage = 0,
        Accounts= accounts3
    });

    //Show the Current Data
    overdues.Dump();

    var result = overdues.Where(a=>a.Accounts.Any(b=>b.AccountId.Equals("JKB2")));

    result.Dump();


}
```

Comment: So do you want to ignore any `overdues` where they have accounts other than `JKB2`? Or do you just want to not see other accounts in your results (i.e. filter the accounts list as well as the overdues list)? Or, looking at Chris' answer, do you want to just see the account objects, and not the overdue models?

Comment: Hi @John_ReinstateMonica I want the Overdues and the Accounts. And after filtering to `JKB2` I should get the Overdue Slabs and its Accounts (So in Accounts only JKB2 should show)

Comment: " I want the result only to have Accounts equalling to JKB2 not Accounts that have JKB2" am I confused....

Comment: @MongZhu I am sorry If what I have written did not understand you. For such, I have made available a Pseudocode in the form of a JSON value. I hope this gives clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filter is correct in terms of it is returning the `OverdueModel` instances that *have* a record; the problem is that you want just the filtered part of the interior `.Accounts`. If we assume that we don't want to *change* all of the objects, you're going to need to create a projection to a new model that contains *just* those filtered accounts. Perhaps something like:

```cs
var results = from outer in overdues
                where outer.Accounts.Any(b => b.AccountId == "JKB2")
                let filtered = outer.Accounts.FindAll(b => b.AccountId == "JKB2")
                select (Record: outer, Accounts: filtered);
```

although a wide range of alternatives are possible. For example, a flatter model would be:

```cs
var results = from outer in overdues
                from account in outer.Accounts
                where account.AccountId == "JKB2"
                select (Record: outer, Account: account);
```

Comment: This is the closest I could get as a solution. Thank You @marc-gravell

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is the SelectMany operator in LINQ, which flattens a sequence of collections.

So try the below

```
var result = overdues.SelectMany(a=>a.Accounts).Where(a=>a.AccountId.Equals("JKB2"))
```

Comment: I think OP wants to still have the outer object.

Comment: Hi @Chris Appreciate your answer. However your answer only gives the Accounts; but I need the Overdue slabs as well associated with `JKB2`